# How do I load pictures to UIImageView keeping its original ratio?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I want to load multiple pictures to `UIImageView` from the Library.

However, the size and ratio of the pictures changes to `UIImageView` size when its loaded and

distort the original pictures.

How do I load the picture to `UIImageView` while keeping its original size?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`UIImageView` does not change the images. It just offers different ways of displaying them. If you want to keep the aspect ratio intact, set the image view's `contentMode` property to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` (the default is `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`).